# DocuSign Carbon Copy Doesn't Receive Note

Tags: ios, swift, docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign's API in an iOS application to sign documents. Everything is going fine, except for the Carbon Copy experience.

I have two signers, with routing orders 1 and 2. Then, I have several CC recipients, all with routing order 3.

When the document is signed, the CC recipients receive an email alerting them that the document was signed, but they don't receive the note they should be getting. I know I'm setting this property well: when the CC recipients have a routing order of 1 or 2, they receive an email with the note, and then they receive an email when the document is signed.

How can I get my CC recipients to receive their email at the right point in time, with the note I want them to see?

Here's the log from DocuSign:

```
POST https://na2.docusign.net:8822/restapi/v2/accounts/6580857/envelopes
Content-Length: 284777
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US; q=1.0
Host: na2.docusign.net
User-Agent: Sales/1.0(iPhone; iOS 9.3.2; Scale/2.00)
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"[email1]","Password":"[omitted]","IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-DocuSign-SDK: Obj-C
X-Forwarded-For: 69.74.21.33
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

{"status":"sent","documents":[{"documentId":"1","documentBase64":"[omitted]","name":"Test Name"}],"emailSubject":"Subject","emailBlurb":"","recipients":{"signers":[{"email":"[email1]","routingOrder":"1","clientUserId":"1001","tabs":"[omitted]", recipientId":"1","name":"John Doe"},{"note":"This is a note that appears during the signing experience","tabs":"[omitted]","email":"[email2]","clientUserId":"1002","routingOrder":"2","recipientId":"2","name":"Jane Doe"}],"carbonCopies":[{"roleName":"Carbon Copy","routingOrder":"3","email":"[email3]","recipientId":"3","note":"This note does not appear in the email sent to the address.","name":"John Smith"}]}}
201 Created
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "envelopeId": "f3421750-6884-4f84-a318-d4637151222c",
  "uri": "/envelopes/f3421750-6884-4f84-a318-d4637151222c",
  "statusDateTime": "2016-07-12T12:51:24.4870000Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

I notice that I'm leaving the email blurb section empty. Could this be a potential solution, or does that field's content get displayed to all parties involved in the signing? In practice, I need to be able to have several different notes for several CC recipients. As far as I know, this can be achieved on DocuSign's website, so I don't see why it couldn't be done through the API.

Comment: Just clarifying: are you referring to the CC recipient viewing the personal NOTE in the email they receive, or during the actual signing experience?

Comment: The personal note in the email. They get an email, but there's no note. Notes work fine for the signers.

Comment: Can you post the envelope create call? You can see it via the API logs. See https://support.docusign.com/articles/API-Request-Logging for details

Comment: Adding the call to the original question. Thanks, I didn't know about this feature!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it seems my problem was caused by a misunderstanding of DocuSign's API. The `note` field is designed to provide a note that only appears during the signing experience, while the `"emailNotification":{"emailSubject":"TEST","emailBody":"TEST"}` field is designed to do what I was trying to achieve.